# Prolog: Distance between cities

Tags: prolog, distance

I'm new to Prolog. I'm trying to make a simple program that find the distance between cities using recursive structure. The problem occurs when I try to find sum distance between cities that are not directly connected (e.g. london to sydney).

```
distance(london,newyork,3.2).
distance(london,capetown,5.8).
distance(london,rome,0.8).
distance(london,panama,4.5).
distance(panama,sydney,7.7).
distance(newyork,sanfrancisco,2.5).
distance(newyork,panama,1.9).
distance(sanfrancisco,sydney,6.2).
distance(sanfrancisco,tokyo,4.5).
distance(tokyo,calcutta,2.5).
distance(tokyo,sydney,4.1).
distance(sydney,calcutta,4.4).
distance(sydney,capetown,6.0).
distance(capetowm,rome,5.1).
distance(calcutta,cairo,2.2).
distance(cairo,rome,0.9).

connected(X,Y,Distance):-
   distance(X,Y,Distance).
connected(X,Y,Distance):-
   distance(X,Z,NewDistance),
   connected(Z,Y,NewDistance),
   Distance is Distance+NewDistance.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your last rule like this:

```
connected(X,Y,Distance):- distance(X,Z,Distance1),
                          distance(Z,Y,Distance2),
                          SumDistance is Distance1+Distance2,
                          write(SumDistance).
```

Here is my result:

```
1 ?- connected(london,sydney,X).
12.2
true .
```

The route is **London -> Panama -> Sydney**. I used `trace.` to see how it works:

```
 2 ?- trace.
true.

[trace] 2 ?- connected(london,sydney,X)
   ....
   Redo: (7) distance(london, _G1945, _G1946) ? creep
   Exit: (7) distance(london, panama, 4.5) ? creep
   Call: (7) distance(panama, sydney, _G1950) ? creep
   Exit: (7) distance(panama, sydney, 7.7) ? creep
   Call: (7) _G1955 is 4.5+7.7 ? creep
   Exit: (7) 12.2 is 4.5+7.7 ? creep
   Call: (7) write(12.2) ? creep
12.2
   Exit: (7) write(12.2) ? creep
   Exit: (6) connected(london, sydney, _G1871) ? creep
```

(I have removed some of the tracing because it was too long).

Comment: It seems like, there is a problem with the solution. I am getting 5.1 instead of 4.5 for `connected(london, panama, X).` Similarly, for all other single predicate execution, the answer is wrong.